# Can I add a variable length member in a SBE composite type?

Tags: java, encoding, binary, streaming

I have a nested data structure that I'm trying to integrate with SBE. One of the nested objects has a string member. How can I definition variable length fields for nested types?

I could potentially redesign my object layout, but am curious if this is supported.

Comment: what means `SBE`?

Comment: https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer from SBE authors - 
https://github.com/real-logic/simple-binary-encoding/issues/485